# Dragging an image view out of collection view into main view

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uipangesturerecognizer

I'm trying to let my users drag an image out of a UICollectionView and onto the main view. However, I have a problem at the stage where said image view is removed from the collection view and added from the main view. The problem is that this seems to halt the tracking of the panning and so the user has to drag the object once to get it into the main view and again for it to go to the desired location. I'm not sure how to resolve this, here's how my code works:

**After creation of image view in cellForItemAt**

```
let panRec = UIPanGestureRecognizer()
panRec.addTarget(self, action:#selector(willDraggedView(_:)))
imageDupe.addGestureRecognizer(panRec)
imageDupe.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

**Switching Views**

```
 func willDraggedView(_ sender:UIPanGestureRecognizer){
        if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.began) {
            if (sender.view?.superview != self.view) {
                sender.view?.removeFromSuperview()
                let orig = viewToOrigin[sender.view as! UIImageView]
                sender.view?.frame = CGRect(x: orig!.x, y: orig!.y + screenWidth+45, width: (sender.view?.frame.width)!, height: (sender.view?.frame.height)!)
                self.view.addSubview(sender.view!)
            }
        }
        draggedView(sender)
    }
```

**Actual Panning**

```
func draggedView(_ sender:UIPanGestureRecognizer){
        let translation = sender.translation(in: self.view)
        let tmp=sender.view?.center.x  //x translation
        let tmp1=sender.view?.center.y //y translation
        sender.view?.layer.cornerRadius = 0
        sender.view?.center=CGPoint(x:tmp!+translation.x, y:tmp1!+translation.y)
        sender.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.view)

        self.view.bringSubview(toFront: sender.view!)
}
```

**Here's the log I'm reading out**

```
2016-11-07 09:06:40.555 ScriptBuilder[93937:18223071] unexpected nil window in __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue, _windowServerHitTestWindow: <UIWindow: 0x7f9013405cd0; frame = (0 0; 375 667); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x608000053290>; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x60800003d7c0>>
```

Comment: You probably move the view with the gesture recognizer through the view hierarchy, which leads to the described crash. Instead you should create a new view (e. g. a frame or a dimmed image) for moving, and reorder the view at the end of the gesture.

Comment: Thanks! Managed to fix it with your advice!!

Comment: @AntersBear Can you please share the project code on how this worked? Or how the view was added to to another view from inside the "cellForItemAt"